# Bootstrap collapse.in requiring two clicks to hide sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My first time posting on here so hopefully I do this correctly!

Here's sample code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
        $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
      });
      $('#stacked-menu li a ').click(function() {
        $(this).next('ul').slideToggle('500');
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-arrow-left glyphicon-arrow-down')
      });
    });
```

```css
#sidebar {
  width: inherit;
  min-width: 220px;
  max-width: 220px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
i {
  color: black;
}
.glyphicon-arrow-down {
  float: right;
  font-size: 8px;
}
.glyphicon-arrow-left {
  float: right;
  font-size: 8px;
}
.nav-container {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
.nav-sub-container {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.nav-stacked ul.nav-stacked > li > a {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.padRight {
  padding-right: 40px;
}
ol {
  margin-left: -40px;
}
a {
  color: black !important;
}
a:hover {
  color: #720000 !important;
}
.size {
  font-size: 12px !important;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        rel="stylesheet" />
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js">
</script>
<script 
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">  
</script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="stacked-menu">
    <li>
        <a class="nav-container"
            data-target="#h1"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-parent="#stacked-menu">
                        Home
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse.in" data-toggle="false" id="h1">
        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#hs1" href="#hs1">
            <a class="nav-sub-container">
                Menu 1
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left padRight"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse size" id="hs1">
            <li><a href="#ss1.1">Sub-section 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ss1.2">Sub-section 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#hs1" href="#hs2">
            <a class="nav-sub-container">
                Menu 2
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left padRight"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse size" id="hs2">
            <li><a href="#ss2.1">Sub-section 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ss2.2">Sub-section 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#hs2" href="#hs3">
            <a class="nav-sub-container">
                Menu 3
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left padRight"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse size" id="hs3">
            <li><a href="#ss3.1">Sub-section 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ss3.2">Sub-section 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ss3.3">Sub-section 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

My issue:
I'm having a problem with my sidebar functionality. I need the sidebar "Menu's" to be open on page load (not sub-sections underneath it, just the Menu's). I accomplished this by adding class collapse.in to my Menu group. However, now when clicking the "Home" link it opens the menu list again, requiring a second click in order to close the sidebar menu. This also messes up the glyphicon animation and faces the arrow the wrong way.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'd like the Menu list to be open on load, but only require one click on the Home link to close the entire sidebar. I'd also like the glyphicon arrow to face the correct way (although this will probably fix itself if I can get the sidebar to close on the first click).

Sorry, I hope that is clear enough. I've only been learning HTML/CSS/JS for a few weeks, so I may not be using the proper terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to separate your classes with spaces (`collapse` and `in` are two different classes):

Change this:

`<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse.in" data-toggle="false" id="h1">`

To this:

`<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse in" data-toggle="false" id="h1">`

Next time provide a code in something like JSFiddle or Codepen, it will be easier and faster :)

Comment: Yes, but I think JSFiddle or Codepen are better because you can easily edit things.

Comment: If you use the "Copy snippet to answer" button, and then click on "edit snippet" in your post, you can edit it in a similar 4 square window.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: Wow... now I feel like an idiot! I read the bootstrap documentation and saw that it showed "collapse.in" but didn't scroll down a little further to see how it was implemented into HTML... sigh. Thank you so much!